# How to get terminal stdout in python

Tags: python, terminal, stdout

Hello i want to get terminal stdout like this

```
>>> print('hello')
hello
>>> print # get terminal contents
'''
>>> print('hello')
hello
'''
```

i was tring to do this

```
import sys
print('Hello')
print(sys.stdout)
```

But it didnt print terminal contents

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot read what is currently displayed on the terminal.  And certainly not via `sys.stdout`, which you cannot safely assume is readable at all.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your end goal?